# This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 With Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, http, request, localhost

I am Working on Codeigniter whenever i use nested loops the localhost cannot handle my Request. Now i Changed My Strategy of Code But having with the same issue.This time i made Functions with for loop inside. 
I want to get Results from two different Queries to Match the columns in nested loops or by using the Function
Code is Attached

```
                  <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                    <?php if($allow_array ->result()){ ?>
                    <thead class="thead" >
                    <th style="width: 10%">Employee Number</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Employee Name</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Location</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Category</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Extra Work Allowance</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Hardship Allowance</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Shift Allowance</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Relocation Allowance</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Production Allowance</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Special Allowance Zin/KUP</th>
                    </thead>
                    <?php }?>
                    <tbody class="tbody">
                <?php



                $cat=" ";
                $loc=" ";
                $ewa=0;
                $hsa=0;
                $sa=0;
                $ra=0;
                $pa=0;
                $sazk=0;


                function values($cat,$loc,$ewa,$hsa,$sa,$ra,$pa,$sazk,$allow_array)
            {
         foreach ($allow_array->result() as $allow) {

    ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 10%"><?php echo $allow->emp_no; ?></td>
                <td style="width: 10%"><?php echo $allow->emp_name; ?></td>
                <td style="width: 10%"><?php echo $allow->loc_name; ?></td>
                <td style="width: 10%"><?php echo $allow->category; ?></td>
                <td style="width: 10%">
                    <?php if (($allow->category == $cat) && ($allow->loc_name == $loc) && ($ewa > 0)) { ?>
                        <input size="5" type="number" min="0" max="99"
                               value="<?php echo $allow->extra_work_allowance; ?>"
                               name="">
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 10%">
                    <?php if (($allow->category == $cat) && ($allow->loc_name == $loc) && ($hsa > 0)) { ?>
                        <input size="5" type="number" min="0" max="1"
                               value="<?php echo $allow->hardship_allowance; ?>"
                               name="">
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 10%">

                    <input size="5" type="number" min="0" max="99"
                           value="<?php echo $allow->shift_allowance; ?>"
                           name="">

                </td>

                <td style="width: 10%">
                    <input size="5" type="number" min="0" max="1"
                           value="<?php echo $allow->relocation_allowance; ?>"
                           name="">

                </td>

                <td style="width: 10%"><input size="5" type="number" min="0" max="99"
                                              value="<?php echo $allow->production_allowance; ?>"
                                              name=""></td>


                <td style="width: 10%"><input size="5" type="number" min="0" max="99"
                                              value="<?php echo $allow->special_allowance_zin_kup; ?>"
                                              name=""></td>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $allow->emp_no ?>" name="empname">

            </tr>

    <?php
              }
            }
                foreach ($allowed_allowances as $allowances) {
                    $cat = $allowances->category;
                    $loc = $allowances->loc_name;
                    $ewa = $allowances->extra_work_allowance;
                    $hsa = $allowances->hardship_allowance;
                    $sa = $allowances->shift_allowance;
                    $ra = $allowances->relocation_allowance;
                    $pa = $allowances->production_allowance;
                    $sazk = $allowances->special_allowance_zin_kup;
                    values($cat,$loc,$ewa,$hsa,$sa,$ra,$pa,$sazk,$allow_array);
                }
                ?>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

I Also Tried to Configure Xampp Server but it does not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try enabling error reporting or check apache error log, So that you can get details of what's going wrong with your code.